# Accessibility API alternative to get selected text from any app in osx

Tags: macos, accessibility, selectedtext

I already wrote a code which sets me able to get the selected text in TextEdit.app or other few apps. My problem is I need to get the selected text in any app. It seems the accessibility API is not capable to get the selected text of every app as I can evidence by using the Accessibility Inspector.

This first image shows how the accessibility API can get the selected text as an attribute from the AXTextArea in the TextEdit.app:

[image: The Accessibility Inspector detecting AXTextArea and AXSelectedText in the Text Edit App]

Then I try to get the same information from TextWrangler.app but it won't work the same way.

[image: The Accessibility Inspector can't detect selected text in the Text Wrangler App]

Is there an alternative to get the selected text information from any app or at least most of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only alternative I know is to send a Cmd-c and monitor the pasteboard:

```
+ (void)sendCommandC
{
    CGKeyCode _C = [[DJRKeyboardTools sharedInstance] keyCodeForChar:'c'];
    CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);
    CGEventRef pasteCommandDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, _C, YES);
    CGEventSetFlags(pasteCommandDown, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);
    CGEventRef pasteCommandUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, _C, NO);

    CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, pasteCommandDown);
    CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, pasteCommandUp);

    CFRelease(pasteCommandUp);
    CFRelease(pasteCommandDown);
    CFRelease(source);    
}
```

That piece of code will post the keyboard event. You'll need a bit more code. These gists of mine can help you to start:

- https://gist.github.com/djromero/7326451 Keyboard events (post a keyboard shortcut)
- https://gist.github.com/djromero/7326432 Keyboard tools (get the right character code)
- https://gist.github.com/djromero/7326400 Monitor pasteboard

Comment: This works and might be accepted as the correct answer. I also want to mention the open source code called Jumpcut.app which implements code that solves this.